# VBA output contents of Array to Word document

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

so what I need to do is fill an array using an InputBox, then but that in an array, sort it alphabetically and then output it to the current word document. I have it almost most complete, the issue is it is only outputting the last word to the document. Im guessing my loop is wrong but I cannot find VBA documentation to do this to save my life. Thank you

```
Option Explicit
```

This is the main sub that declares the array

```
Sub Main()

Dim ListArr() As String

ListArr = Get_Input_List()

Call Bubble_Sort_Ascending(ListArr)

Call Output_List_To_Document(ListArr)

End Sub
```

Function to get input and fill array

```
Function Get_Input_List() As String()

Dim list As String

list = InputBox("Please enter words to sort separated with a comma and no spaces", "Words")
Get_Input_List = Split(list, ",")

End Function
```

Sorts the array alphabetically

```
Sub Bubble_Sort_Ascending(listNewArray() As String)

Dim SrtTemp As Variant
Dim inputWord As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

'Alphabetize Sheet Names in Array List
For i = LBound(listNewArray) To UBound(listNewArray)
     For j = i To UBound(listNewArray)
         If listNewArray(i) > listNewArray(j) Then
             SrtTemp = listNewArray(j)
             listNewArray(j) = listNewArray(i)
             listNewArray(i) = SrtTemp
         End If
     Next j
 Next i


End Sub
```

This is the problem, I cannot output the whole array to the word document. I have found plenty of documentation on how to do this into an excel spreadsheet but almost nothing for word.

```
Sub Output_List_To_Document(newListArray() As String)

Dim inputWord As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

For i = LBound(newListArray) To UBound(newListArray)
     For j = i To UBound(newListArray)
        For Each inputWord In newListArray
            ActiveDocument.Range = inputWord & vbCrLf
        Next
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Output_List_To_Document` has three nested loops. Is this intentional? Your inner `For Each` should be sufficient. Also, consider using the `Join` function, with `vbCrLf` as a delimiter to build a complete string, and then you can append the entire array in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over-writing `ActiveDocument.Range` each time through the loop.  If you want to append to the end of it, you need to collapse the range to it's ending position:

```
Sub Output_List_To_Document(newListArray() As String)
    Dim inputWord As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim insertPos As Range
    Set insertPos = ActiveDocument.Range

    For i = LBound(newListArray) To UBound(newListArray)
         For j = i To UBound(newListArray)
            For Each inputWord In newListArray
                insertPos.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                insertPos = inputWord & vbCrLf
            Next
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Note** - It isn't clear why you're looping through the array with 3 nested loops.  If you only need to write each word once, I suspect you're *really* looking for something more like this:

```
Sub Output_List_To_Document(newListArray() As String)
    Dim insertPos As Range
    Set insertPos = ActiveDocument.Range

    Dim inputWord As Variant
    For Each inputWord In newListArray
        insertPos.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'Value 0, Can ignore writing it as well
        insertPos = inputWord & vbCrLf
    Next
End Sub
```